# Installing AWS CLI on EC2 instances via Spinnaker/Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, spinnaker

Are there any security considerations in terms of installing the `AWS CLI` by making as part of baking an image AMI?

I can see the following ways in which AWS CLI can be installed:

```
1. Via baking image (i.e. making AWS CLI as part of Base AMI itself)
2. Via cloud init
3. Install it as pre-requisite just before your service bootstraps.
```

I see a strong NO (from internal community) on the above for the reason that the AWS instance (spinnaker managed) can do more than just accessing cloud native resources and is very powerful. So In this case, if we tighten the spinnaker IAM role in which it deploys instances, should it be fine?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what are you going to do with the AWS CLI in each EC2 baked instance. IS it for debugging purposes? is it part of the functionality of your system?
if is debugging only you can enable AWS CLI but leave an AWS IAM role with minimum permissions attached. You could have a role with special permissions that you can attach to your desired instances, access the instance and perform your debugging actions.

Other than that it really is not recommended that you use AWs CLI or package installation managers inside instances.